# Trouble building Samsung BLE SDK sample application

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I'm new to Android development, trying to build an app that utilizes Samsung BLE technology to detect when an Android phone is within range of other mobile devices generating a BLE signal. I tried to get the proximity PXP sample app working from http://developer.samsung.com/ble. The site says to "Please use the global Google BLE API for Android versions 4.3 and later." I'm running 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S5, and I'm not sure how to get this app working. I tried downloading the recent API versions 20 and 21 and building on Eclipse with no luck. I'm getting a bunch of errors saying that my BluetoothGatt classes can't be resolved. Any ideas how to get this working? And is it even possible to get my Samsung device to transmit a BLE signal to be picked up by similar devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this sample to work, you need a Samsung Android device with the official Samsung Android 4.2.x system image. Only these system images have the Samsung-customized bluetooth stack needed to work with this Samsung BLE SDK.

Samsung abandoned their BLE SDK when built-in BLE support was added to Android 4.3.  The examples do not work on later OS versions because the required customized Bluetooth stack is not present for the Samsung BLE SDK to use.

If you are targeting phones with 4.3 or higher, you cannot use this SDK, and should instead use the build in Android BLE APIs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

If you really need to target Samsung 4.2 devices, you can use the Samsung BLE SDK as well, but you must write totally different code to run when you are on that platform.  This is precisely what I did when adding support for Samsung 4.2 devices with the Android Beacon Library: https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library/tree/samsung-ble-sdk